# How to label the points on a qqplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `geom_text` to label the points on a qq-plot in ggplot2. I am following the documentation of [aesthetic evaluation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) Using the `after_stat` function. The computed stats are labeled theoretical, and sample as seen in the documentation in of `geom_qq` [computed variables](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html?q=geom_qq#computed-variables) and should be available to use in the `geom_text`? This is my first time using `after_stat` so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example of what I have attempted:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- iris
dat$row <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(sample = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = row,
                x = after_stat(theoretical),
                y = after_stat(sample))) #Trying to label points on qq plot
#> Error in `geom_text()`:
#> ! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
```

Also tried this way to modify instead of `geom_qq` to do `geom_text`

```
dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(sample = Petal.Length, label = row)) +
  geom_qq(geom = "text") +
  geom_qq_line()
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: label.
#> ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: label.
#> ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?
#> Error in `geom_qq()`:
#> ! Problem while setting up geom.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
#> ! `geom_text()` requires the following missing aesthetics: label.
```

Comment: The errors you are getting are because you can only access those variables with `after_stat()` if you actually use that `stat` in your `geom`. So it would have to look something like `geom_text(aes(x = after_stat(theoretical), y = after_stat(sample), label = row), stat = 'qq')`. Yet, that doesn't work either, because the label gets dropped. I'm not sure why though!

Comment: Interesting in the example of this functionality `ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density))) +
  geom_density()` they don't adjust the stat parameter. I made the github issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5794 because it does feel buggy to me.

Comment: That's because `geom_histogram` has `stat = "bin"` as default, which computes the density.

Comment: What I am doing in the meantime is calculate the quantiles directly on the data frame and use `geom_point` and `geom_label` directly instead of relying on the `qq` geoms.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the right approach.

Comment: In the future, when you post a github issue like that, it's polite to link the stackoverflow post so the `ggplot2` devs don't have to spent time telling you things that have already been pointed out here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Axeman you have to use `stat="qq"` in `geom_text` too, to add labels to your qqplot based on the values of `sample` and `theoretical`.

However, in general a stat transforms the original dataset and some aesthetics get dropped at all, e.g. `stat="qq"` understands or supports only `x`, `y`, `group` and `sample` and hence all other aesthetics get dropped before the statistical transformation. As a consequence, the `label=` aes gets dropped, which means that there is no longer a `label` column in the transformed data (the same would also happen if you want to use the `color` aes to e.g. color by `Species`). And hence we get an an error as `geom_text` requires a `label=` aes.

Instead, one option to label your points based on the `row` column of your original data when using `stat="qq"` would be order the `row` column by `Petal.Length` aka the variable mapped on `sample` and map the reordered column on the `label` aes using `after_stat`, i.e. use `after_stat(dat$row[order(dat$Petal.Length)])`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- iris
dat$row <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat |>
  ggplot(aes(sample = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() +
  geom_text(aes(
    label = after_stat(
      dat$row[order(dat$Petal.Length)]
    ),
    x = after_stat(theoretical),
    y = after_stat(sample + 1)
  ), stat = "qq", vjust = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you +1 for the y axis?

Comment: Sorry. That was just to shift the labels. Should have mentioned that.